# Docker-compose Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to create and connect to postgres database using the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: username 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password 
      POSTGRES_DB: default_database
```

When I run the docker-compose up command from my command prompt I see this output:

```
C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\DOCKER_COMPOSE>docker compose up
[+] Running 14/14
 ✔ database 13 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                                                                                                                                           62.8s
   ✔ 9e3ea8720c6d Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        17.0s
   ✔ 7782b3e1be4b Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        17.6s
   ✔ 247ec4ff783a Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        18.5s
   ✔ f7ead6900700 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        19.2s
   ✔ e7afdbe9a191 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        20.2s
   ✔ 3ef71fe7cece Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        20.9s
   ✔ 1459ebb56be5 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        21.6s
   ✔ 3595124f6861 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        22.3s
   ✔ dd8e229a2a13 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        52.0s
   ✔ 8cf43a35dc10 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        52.9s
   ✔ 2fac9b4aab2f Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        53.8s
   ✔ b3f90da87261 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        54.5s
   ✔ 5f7e3ef14a3b Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                        55.1s
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network docker_compose_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                         0.3s
 ✔ Container docker_compose-database-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                                         8.0s
Attaching to docker_compose-database-1
docker_compose-database-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
docker_compose-database-1  | This user must also own the server process.
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
docker_compose-database-1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
docker_compose-database-1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
docker_compose-database-1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
docker_compose-database-1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
docker_compose-database-1  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
docker_compose-database-1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
docker_compose-database-1  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
docker_compose-database-1  | creating configuration files ... ok
docker_compose-database-1  | running bootstrap script ... ok
docker_compose-database-1  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
docker_compose-database-1  | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
docker_compose-database-1  | initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
docker_compose-database-1  | syncing data to disk ... ok
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  | waiting for server to start....2023-05-07 17:09:07.975 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:08.057 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:08.292 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-05-07 17:09:05 UTC
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:08.382 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
docker_compose-database-1  |  done
docker_compose-database-1  | server started
docker_compose-database-1  | CREATE DATABASE
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:09.195 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
docker_compose-database-1  | waiting for server to shut down....2023-05-07 17:09:09.279 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:09.281 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:09.284 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:09.368 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
docker_compose-database-1  | .2023-05-07 17:09:11.136 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 918 buffers (5.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.146 s, sync=1.209 s, total=1.852 s; sync files=250, longest=0.657 s, average=0.005 s; distance=4217 kB, estimate=4217 kB
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:11.143 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
docker_compose-database-1  |  done
docker_compose-database-1  | server stopped
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
docker_compose-database-1  |
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:11.465 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:11.466 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:11.466 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:11.602 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:11.870 UTC [64] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-05-07 17:09:10 UTC
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:09:11.971 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:14:11.918 UTC [62] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
docker_compose-database-1  | 2023-05-07 17:14:18.077 UTC [62] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 44 buffers (0.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=4.571 s, sync=0.752 s, total=6.159 s; sync files=12, longest=0.267 s, average=0.063 s; distance=252 kB, estimate=252 kB
```

Next I run the docker inspect command to figure out the Ip.Address and I get: "IPAddress": "172.30.0.2"

When I try to connect on dbeaver to the db inserting all the data I get: "The connection attempt timed out"

How can I solve??

Comment: The IP address is not necessary. The relevant port (`5432`) is published on the host. Just connect to `localhost:5432`.

Comment: If I use localhost on dbeaver i recieve error about password but th password is correct

Comment: Are you using the correct username (`username`)? Do you connect to the correct database (`default_database`)?